# get calculated date cell in PHPExcel

Tags: datetime, phpexcel, datetime-format

I used PHPExcle to import an excel file. I found I could not get correct value from a calculated cell.
The calculated value is `8月27日`(a date in Chinese) in that cell, it means `27 August` in English.
The cell references to A1 in Sheet2, and A1 in Sheet2 references to a cell in another excel file.

I've already tried some ways as below:

```
  echo $cell->getValue();               // =Sheet2!A2
  echo $cell->__toString();             // =Sheet2!A2
  echo $cell->getCalculatedValue();     // #REF!
  echo $cell->getFormattedValue();      // #REF!
  echo $cell->getOldCalculatedValue();  // 41878 (a strange result, I don't know what it means)
```

How can I get the correct value(`8月27日`) in PHPExcel?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `41878` result that you get from the call to `getOldCalculatedValue();` is an MS Excel serialized date/timestamp.

In MS Excel, a date or time value is measured as the number of days since 1st January 1900 (or 1st January 1904 if using the Mac 1904 calendar) and imply stored as a number. It's only the number format mask for the cell that renders it as a date and/or time

`41878` is the number that corresponds to 27th August 2014 in the normal Windows 1900 Calendar.

PHPExcel has functions built-in to convert that MS Excel serialized date/timestamp to either a unix timestamp or a PHP DateTime object

```
$unixTimeStamp = PHPExcel_Shared_Date::ExcelToPHP($cell->getOldCalculatedValue());
```

and then use the normal PHP date functions to format it

or you can use

```
$dateTimeObject = PHPExcel_Shared_Date::ExcelToPHPObject($cell->getOldCalculatedValue());
```

and use normal PHP DateTime object methods to format it

Comment: one more question, can I get `OldCalculatedValue` via `$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->toArray()` or another method like that? I've looked into the 4 parameters of `toArray()`, it seems no way.

Comment: No, the only option for `getOldCalculatedValue();` is to call it for individual cells